# Implementing Quicksort

Tags: java, quicksort

i am trying to implement quicksort but i am not getting correct results. Here is my code:

```
public static void quickSort(Comparable[] a, int start, int stop) {
    if (start < stop) {
        int pivot = partition(a, start ,stop);
        System.out.print("Pivot: "+a[pivot]+" Array: ");
        printArray(a);
        quickSort(a,start,pivot-1);
        quickSort(a,pivot+1, stop);
    }       
}

public static int partition(Comparable[] a, int start, int stop) {
    Comparable pivot = a[stop];
    int i = start;
    int j = stop-1;


     while (i < j) {
            while( (isLess(a[i], pivot)|| isEqual(a[i], pivot)))
                i++;
            while((isGreater(a[j], pivot)|| isEqual(a[j], pivot)))
                j--;
            if(i < j)
                swap(a, i,j);
        } 

    swap(a,i, stop);

    return i;

}
```

For input: {51,17,82,10,97,6,23,45,6,73}, i am getting result: 6 6 10 17 23 45 51 73 97 82 
For input: {12,9,4,99,120,1,3,10}, i am getting an index out of bounds error. Would appreciate some help in where i am going wrong.

Comment: @Julian it does not make sense to swap the same item with itself... If `i==j`, exactly that would happen if the condition in the if was `i<=j`. Same with the while...

Comment: Your problem is so small. Learn to debug. It will come in handy in the future. You can inspect your program instruction after instruction and see where it fails.

Comment: @ppterka You are right - my mistake - posted a snippet with slightly differnt logic for you extracted from the site in the link in my previous comment - You will see an extra  i++ and j-- This gives you one more step.

Comment: (Irk: why do people upvote localized non-question code-reviews?)

Answer (score 1):

Your two problems are unrelated.

The problem with `{51,17,82,10,97,6,23,45,6,73}` is — what happens when `stop == start + 1`? Then `i == start == stop - 1 == j`, so you never enter the `while`-loop, so you unconditionally `swap(a, i, stop)` — even if `a[i]` was *already* less than `a[stop]`.

The problem with `{12,9,4,99,120,1,3,10}` is seemingly that you didn't read the stacktrace. ;-)   Assuming you have a decent Java compiler and JVM, it should have given you the exact line-number and problematic index, so you would have seen that the problem is in this line:

```
            while((isGreater(a[j], pivot)|| isEqual(a[j], pivot)))
```

once `j` gets to `-1`. (This will happen if `pivot` is the very least value in the range of interest.) You just need to add a check for that:

```
            while(j > start && (isGreater(a[j], pivot)|| isEqual(a[j], pivot)))
```

(and, for that matter, for the corresponding case of `i`:

```
            while(i < stop && (isLess(a[i], pivot)|| isEqual(a[i], pivot)))
```

)

. . . and you need to learn how to debug your code. :-)

Comment: thnx alot!! btw i did figure these out after debugging but i wanst sure how to fix it!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [Algorithms: Design and Analysis](https://www.coursera.org/course/algo), very good internet course from Stanford. After this course you will write such codes more easily. It is a bit enhanced version, pivot is chosen as a median of three. Note that you don't have to write your own `printArray()` function. In Java you can do it with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers))`. Also you can observe how to call `quickSort()` in more elegant way, with only one argument, using method overloading.

```
public class QuickSort
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int numbers[] =
    { 51, 17, 82, 10, 97, 6, 23, 45, 6, 73 };
    quickSort(numbers);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}

public static void quickSort(int[] array)
{
    quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
}

private static void quickSort(int[] array, int left, int right)
{
    if (left >= right)
    {
        return;
    }
    int pivot = choosePivot(array, left, right);
    pivot = partition(array, pivot, left, right);
    quickSort(array, left, pivot - 1);
    quickSort(array, pivot + 1, right);
}

private static int partition(int[] array, int pivot, int left, int right)
{
    swap(array, pivot, left);
    pivot = left;
    int i = left + 1;
    for (int j = left + 1; j <= right; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] < array[pivot])
        {
            swap(array, j, i);
            i++;
        }
    }
    swap(array, pivot, i - 1);
    return i - 1;
}

private static void swap(int[] array, int j, int i)
{
    int temp = array[j];
    array[j] = array[i];
    array[i] = temp;
}

private static int choosePivot(int[] array, int left, int right)
{
    return medianOfThree(array, left, (left + right) / 2, right);
    // return right;
}

private static int medianOfThree(int[] array, int aIndex, int bIndex, int cIndex)
{
    int a = array[aIndex];
    int b = array[bIndex];
    int c = array[cIndex];
    int largeIndex, smallIndex;
    if (a > b)
    {
        largeIndex = aIndex;
        smallIndex = bIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        largeIndex = bIndex;
        smallIndex = aIndex;
    }
    if (c > array[largeIndex])
    {
        return largeIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        if (c < array[smallIndex])
        {
            return smallIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            return cIndex;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: i had done this overloading for the other sorting algorithms i implemented...i just wanted make this work first!! thnx though :)

Comment: hey adam,
I was trying to understand quicksort with median-of-3 partitioning. After finding the median of the first, middle and last element in an array, a common practice is to swap median with the second last element in array(n-1th index). Is there a specific reason that is done?

Comment: @ueg1990 Where have you found that this is a common practice?

Comment: i have seen many examples online where, after finding the median of the 3 elements, the median is then swapped with the second last element. Here are two of the links: 
http://www.java2s.com/Book/Java/Examples/Quick_Sort_Implementation_with_median_of_three_partitioning_and_cutoff_for_small_arrays.htm

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~lavender/courses/ee360c/lectures/lecture-22.pdf